# Batch splitting an array element in nested loop

Tags: arrays, loops, sorting, batch-file, for-loop

```
@echo off 

set hosts[1]=192.168.1.1
set hosts[2]=192.168.1.2
set hosts[3]=192.168.1.3
set hosts[4]=192.168.1.4

set hostcreds[1]=root:pw1!
set hostcreds[2]=root:pw2!
set hostcreds[3]=root:pw3!
set hostcreds[4]=root:pw4!

for /L %%a in (1,1,4) do (

 CALL ECHO Host: %%hosts[%%a]%%>>file%%a.txt

  for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%A in ("%%hostcreds[%%a]%%") do (
   CALL ECHO User: %%A Pass: %%B>>file%%a.txt
  )

)
```

The output is 4 text files named file1 through 4.txt with the contents of "Host: [host IP]" (line return) "User: root:pw1 Pass:" but I would like the output to split "root:pw1" so the output looks like "User: root Pass: pw1".

Why is my for /F not splitting this array element into %%A and %%B? If I remove the array element and change it to just plain text it splits fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the command for your inner `FOR` loop, use the `CALL` command to expand the array value *before* you process the results. This way the value is parsed before it is split by the `FOR` delimiters. By doing this, you no longer need the `CALL` statement when writing the credentials.

Here is the updated script:

```
@echo off 

set hosts[1]=192.168.1.1
set hosts[2]=192.168.1.2
set hosts[3]=192.168.1.3
set hosts[4]=192.168.1.4

set hostcreds[1]=root:pw1!
set hostcreds[2]=root:pw2!
set hostcreds[3]=root:pw3!
set hostcreds[4]=root:pw4!

for /L %%a in (1,1,4) do (

 CALL ECHO Host: %%hosts[%%a]%%>>file%%a.txt

  for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%A in ('CALL ECHO %%hostcreds[%%a]%%') do (
   ECHO User: %%A Pass: %%B>>file%%a.txt
  )

)
```